# Erro ao executar o pull do Git usando o OpenShift

Tags: git, github, openshift

Estou tentando seguir [o tutorial](https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/mediawiki-example) para o OpenShift.

Porém no 3º tem do passo 3 : `$ git pull -s recursive -X theirs upstream master`

Tenho o seguinte erro:

> fatal: unable to connect to github.com: github.com[0: 192.30.252.130]:
>   errno=No error

O que pode ser? Configurações de Proxy ou limitações do serviço na OpenShift .

Comment: Teve algum retorno ao fazer o `git remote`? (passo anterior ao `git pull`)

Comment: o firewall tá configurado para liberar tráfego para fora da rede do OpenShift?